# $36$ pens and $42$ pencils cost $\$460$. How much for $18$ pens and $21$ pencils? Different approaches give different answers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ratio

> Cost of $36$ pens and $42$ pencils is $\$460$. What is the cost of $18$ pens and $21$ pencils?

Solution:

**Method 1: Unitary method**

```
36 pens and 42 pencils costs $460
36 pens and 1 pencil will cost $460/42
1 pen   and 1 pencil will cost $460/(42*36)
1 pen and 21 pencils will cost ($460/(42*36))*21
18 pens and 21 pencils will cost ($460/(42*36))*21 *18
```

Answer is  $115$.

**Method 2: Direct proportion**

```
Cost is ∝ Total number of items
Therefore,
*(Cost/Total number of items)=k(constant)*
 (460/78)=(x/39)
 x=230
```

Answer is $230$.

**Correct answer is given as $230$.**

Comment: Right at the start, without even really knowing much about math, just common sense, the only way it makes sense for 36 pens and 1 pencil to cost $460/42 is if the pens were free.

Comment: If $x$ is the cost of a pen and $y$ is the cost of a pencil, then we are told that $36x+42y=460$.  That is not enough information to find the cost of a pen or pencil individually, and certainly not enough information to find the cost of $36$ pens and $1$ pencil.  Your first "method" where you divided by $42$... you get $\dfrac{36x+42y}{42}=\dfrac{460}{42}$ which would have given $\dfrac{36}{42}x + 1y=\dfrac{460}{42}$ is the cost of $\frac{36}{42}$'ths of a pen and one pencil... not the cost of $36$ pens and one pencil.

Comment: Method 1 fails at the first step - why do you divide by $42$ when only the number of pencils reduces by a factor of $42$? Suppose $36$ pens and $42$ pencils cost $\$780$, because they all cost $\$10$ each. Then $36$ pens and one pencil will cost $\$370$ and there is no division by $42$.

Comment: Note however that $\dfrac{36x+42y}{2}=18x+21y$

Comment: if $36x+42y=460$, then $36x+y\neq 460/42$

Comment: How about solving this simultaneously?

Comment: @JosephHulme One would need a second relation between pens and pencils.

Comment: @higgs I would be skeptical that the OP understands the second method correctly however.  I would worry that if we were to say that $36$ pens and $42$ pencils cost $460$ and we were to ask what $36$ pens and $3$ pencils costs, that the OP might incorrectly say "*well, the number of total items being purchased decreased by half so the cost should decrease by half too*" when that ignores the possibility of pens being more expensive than pencils.  What is important here is that we specifically decreased the number of pens by half *and* the number of pencils by half.

Comment: @higgs, actually in this question, we don't need another equation, because the value of the second equation is half the first equation

Comment: @JMoravitz Quite right, good observation. I think that to answer this question, one needs only to see that the quantities of pens *and* pencils have dropeed in quantity equally, rahter than as you say, a possible other number of either object.

Comment: @DevanshKamra higgs was referring to Joseph's comment about "solving simultaneously" which implies that Joseph was trying to find the individual costs of pens and the individual costs of pencils, which is as higgs correctly noted impossible with the given information.  You are correct that for the problem as originally written this is not necessary, but would have been necessary were we to use Joseph's suggested approach.

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh okay, I'm sorry. You're correct.

Comment: @DevanshKamra So by that logic, is there only **one** way to choose a number of pens and pencils such that the total cost is equal to $230? EDIT Oh wait I see you have talked to JM about this already.

Comment: The second method assumes pens and pencils cost the same.  I'd say: Method 1) is meaningless gibberish and unsalvageable.  You may as well count how many times a black cat pukes for all its relevance.   ANd method 2) is wrong but in this case gives a correct answer.

Comment: $36a + 42b=460$ and we can multiply and divide both sides by anything to get a true statement.  Can figure that as long as we buy pens and pencils in a $\frac {36}{42}=\frac 67$ ratio we can solve this but we can't solve this if we buy pens and pencils in any other ratio.  We have $6a + 7b = 76\frac 23$ and so $18a  + 21b = 230$ (or just divide in half from the start).  But we can *ONLY* do this because we are buying pencils and pencils in the same proportions.

Comment: Oh.  Now I see what the unitary method was supposed to be!  $36a + 42b = 460$ so $(36a+42b)\div 42 = 460\div 42$ and if you foul up the distributing the division you incorrectly get $(36a + 42b)\div 42 =$(!!WRONG!!!)$ 36a + 42b\div 42 = 36a+b$.... It should be $(36a + 42b)\div 42 = \frac 67 a + b$ and $\frac 67a + b =\frac {460}{42}$.

Comment: @fleablood In reference to yur first comment; this is an excellent point to make, that may well be lost in the original (original source) of the question. I presume that when ratio is utilised in this way (potentially high school) the point you made may not be covered, but it is clear that this should be mentioned *a priori* in big black letters!

Comment: If the question is If $36pens + 42pencils = 460$ what is $18pens + 21 pencils$ then Method 2) is *not* the correct way to do it.  the "unitary" way to do it:  $\frac 12(36pens + 42pencils) = \frac 12\cdot 460\implies 18pens + 21 pencils = 230$ is the correct way to do but the OP botched it horribly.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing unitary wrong.

If you have $A + B = C$ and you divide $B$ and $C$ by $42$ you must divide *both* terms $A, B$ by $42$.

$36a + 42b = 460$ So

$\frac {36a + 42b}{42} = \frac {460}{42}$ is the next step.

$36a + \frac {42}b= \frac {460}{42}$ is completely wrong.

So $\frac {36}{42}a + b = \frac {460}{42}$

So $\frac 67 a+b = \frac {230}{21}$.

Now then $21(\frac 67 a + b) = 21*\frac {230}{21}$ will give us

$\frac {21*6}7a + 21b =230$

$18a + 21b = 230$ and we are done.

But notice we got lucky.  We were asked to solve something that was proportional.

If we wear asked to find out how much $20$ pens and $15$ pencils cost we wouldn't get anywhere.

$\frac {36}{42}a + b = \frac {460}{42}$ so

$15(\frac {36}{42}a + b) = 15\frac {460}{42}$ so

$\frac {15*6}{7}a + 15b = \frac {230*15}{21}$

$\frac {90}7a + 15 b = \frac {1150}7$

But that doesn't help us because $\frac {90}7\ne 30$

Or we could do it

$\frac {20}{36}(36a + 42b) = \frac {20}{36}460$

so $20a + \frac{70}3 b = \frac {1840}{9}$

But that doesn't help us because $\frac {70}3 \ne 15$.

We can *not* solve it unless pens and pencils are bought in the same proportions.

.....

Method 2) makes the unjustified assumptions that pens and pencils cost the same.  In this case that didn't matter.  Was we are buying the pens and pencils in the same proportions, they *could* for all we know, cost the same.  But in general this wouldn't work.

If pens and pencils both cost $\frac {460}{36+42} = \frac {460}{78} = \frac {230}{39}$ each, then yes buying $39$ pens and pencils will by $230$.

But what if pens cost $10$ and pencils cost $\frac{460 - 36*10}{42} = \frac{100}{42} =\frac {50}{21}$.

Well, we would still have $18$ pens and $21$ pencils cost $18*10 + \frac {50}{21}*21 = 180 + 50 = 230$.

But that's because we bought them in proportion.

If I asked how much $20$ pens and $15$ pencils cost, this method we figure $(20+15)*\frac {230}{39}= \frac {35*230}{39}=206\frac {16}{39}$.

But the real answer would be $20*10 + 15*\frac {50}{21}= 200+\frac{250}7= 235\frac 57$.

Answer (score 0):

This ridiculous question is now alive for many hours, and has not been deleted by the CRUDE militia.

Given such data [Occam's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) tells us to make the simplest assumptions compatible with the data. The simplest assumptions are that there is a prize $a$ for a pen and a prize $b$ for a pencil. More complicated tariffs dealing with the prices of various numbers of pens and of pencils should have been announced in the statement of the problem. Given that
$$36 a+42 b=460$$
it is then obvious that
$$18 a+21 b={1\over2}(36a+42 b)=230\ .$$